# AWS Step Function with Lambda Function input JSON parsing error

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS `Step Function` that calls `Lambda Function`s for each state and I'm passing a `LinkedList` of `PartETag` objects from one state to another for a `MultipartUpload`.

Not sure if it'll help, but here's the code snippet:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import UploadJob;
import UploadJobParameters;

public class JobFinishHandler implements RequestHandler<ExportJobParameters, ExportJobParameters> {

    @Override
    public ExportJobParameters handleRequest(ExportJobParameters parameters, Context context) {

        UploadJob uploadJob = new UploadJob(parameters, context);
        context.getLogger().log("JobFinishHandler");
        context.getLogger().log("parameters: " + parameters.toString());
        context.getLogger().log("parameters.getPartETags().size(): " + parameters.getPartETags().size());
        context.getLogger().log(parameters.getPartETags().toString());
        context.getLogger().log("parameters.getPartETags().hashCode(): " + parameters.getPartETags().hashCode());
        uploadJob.continueS3UploadStream();
        uploadJob.jobFinish();
        uploadJob.jobAbort();
        return parameters;
    }

}
```

This is the input for the state:

`{
  "uploadId":"1234567890",
  "partETags":[
    {
      "partNumber":1,
      "ETag":"67c335990ba21ff95db1d09a3c2c4a11"
    }
  ]
}`

I get this error:

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@369f73a2; line: 1, column: 458] (through reference chain: gov.osdls.exportservices.export.common.ExportJobParameters["partETags"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@369f73a2; line: 1, column: 458] (through reference chain: gov.osdls.exportservices.export.common.ExportJobParameters["partETags"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1106)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:296)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)
```

I checked the `PartETag` class to see if there's a default constructor and there isn't so I'm going to override this class and make a default constructor. But I feel like since `PartETag` is an amazon object, shouldn't they have thought of this already? Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are adding multiple steps to handle multi part upload? Share code snippet.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder yes, it is a step function that keeps uploading parts of a MultipartUpload until it's done. this error is thrown even before the lambda is called and the step function is parsing the input though. I'll still share code just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody is looking for the answer to this question, I just created a custom class that extends `PartETag` and converted the list before completing the `MultipartUpload`:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PartETag;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.Jackson;

public class PartETagExt extends PartETag {

    public PartETagExt() {
        super(0, "a");
    }

    public PartETagExt(PartETag partETag) {
        super(partETag.getPartNumber(), partETag.getETag());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Jackson.toJsonString(this);
    }
}
```

then converted the list to regular `PartETag`:

```
List<PartETag> partETags = new LinkedList<PartETag>();
partETags.addAll(partETagExts);
CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = 
                new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, key, uploadId, partETags);
```